# How do I merge two columns' data into one column and identify each entry by type?

Tags: r, merge

I have a data frame:

```
>head(df, 5)
                 date  time loads unloads
1 2018-04-02 01:00:00 01:00   100    3462
2 2018-04-02 02:00:00 02:00    35    2031
3 2018-04-02 03:00:00 03:00     0    1734
4 2018-04-02 04:00:00 04:00  1908    2499
5 2018-04-02 05:00:00 05:00   333    3069
```

I want to merge the values of both the `loads` and `unloads` columns into a single column, and merely repeat the value in `date` for each new row and list the `type` in another column.

To help explain, each row would be split into two rows and the resulting data frame would look like this:

```
                 date  time  count    type
1 2018-04-02 01:00:00 01:00    100    load
2 2018-04-02 01:00:00 01:00   3462  unload
3 2018-04-02 02:00:00 02:00     35    load
4 2018-04-02 02:00:00 02:00   2031  unload
```

and so on.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can use `melt` or `gather` i.e. `tidyr::gather(df, count, type, loads:unloads)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `gather` from `tidyr` to reshape it to 'long' format

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df, count, type, loads:unloads)
```